# Unreachable code, compilation error vicious circle

Tags: java, compilation

So I have made a programme that calculates the cost of of a ticket based on a number of factors I'll post the question i got below

```
Create a program that given a number of tickets (maximum of 10), 
        the type of ticket (return, one way), the passenger type (under 10, under 16, 
        student, over 60, other), the selected route, and the starting and finishing 
        stops (in the form of a number where n denotes stopn ), 
        calculates the total cost for the journey. 
        The cost of each ticket should be calculated as follows:
                • The cost per mile is 50p;
                • Under 10 travel free when accompanied by an adult; 
                  otherwise, a discount of 75% is applied;
                • Under 16 get a 50% discount;
                • Students get a 25% discount;
                • Over 60’s get a 60% discount.
                Train routes should be expressed in the format:
                int [n] route = {stop2 , stop3 , ... stopNPlusOne};
                Example:
                int [4] route1 = {3, 5, 2, 6};

                 denotes a route with 5 stops: 
                 the distance between stop one and two is 3 miles, 
                 between stop two and three is 5 miles, 
                 between stop three and four is 2, 
                 and between stop four and five is 6.
```

My code is as follows

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Tickets  (Max 10): ");
        int numberOfTickets = input.nextInt();

    if (numberOfTickets > 10) {
        System.out.println("Please choose less than 10 tickets");
    } else {
        double cost = route();
        double totalCost = (cost * numberOfTickets);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.printf("Your total cost is:", totalCost);
    }
}

// DECLARE A NEW METHOD THAT CALCULATES THE DISTANCES TRAVELLED
public static double route() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] route = { 7, 12, 13, 17, 22, 26 }; // miles between each stop

    System.out.println("Enter the first station number(0 - 5): ");
    int firstStation = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the last station number(0 - 5): ");
    int lastStation = input.nextInt();

    int totalMiles = 0;
    for (int i = firstStation; i < lastStation; i++) {
        totalMiles = totalMiles + route[i]; // Total miles
    }
    System.out.println(totalMiles);
    double cost = totalMiles * 0.5; // (* 0.5) because it's 50p per mile.
    System.out.println("The initial cost is £" + cost);

    System.out.println("Please enter your age");
    int age = input.nextInt();
    double totalCost = 0;
    int adults = 0;
    return adults;
    {
        {

    if ((age < 10) && (age > 0)) {
        cost = (cost * 0.25);
    } else if ((age < 16) && (age >= 10)) {
        cost = (cost * 0.5);
    } else if (age > 60) {
        cost = (cost * 0.4);
    }

    System.out.println("Are you a student, if yes enter 1 if not enter 2");
    int studentPass = input.nextInt();
    boolean Student = false;
    if (studentPass == 1)


    {
        Student = true;
    }
    if (studentPass == 2) {
        adults++;
    }

    return cost;
}
}
}
}
}
```

The issue is there is an error on the last curly bracket and so when i delete it everything from return adults and down is said to be unreachable code.

Apologies for the vast amount of text in the question. I'm in java by the way.

Comment: if you dont conditionally return adults, the code below it simply cant ever be reached. The compiler is trying to help you here... I suspect you want to break this into two methods.

Comment: Please remember to choose a best answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple returns in the same function. When a return executes the function exits meaning that the code below will never be able to be run and thus it is unreachable.
So in this:

```
public int function(){
value = 0
//do stuff
return value
//do more things
}
```

"do more things: will never be able to be run because the function stops running as soon as `return value` is encountered. This code is said to be unreachable. 
 Put your code in multiple functions, each with only one return, and then call those functions from your main or wherever you want to use them as necessary

Comment: Thanks a lot good clear answer, I've now sorted it by removing the return adults statement. A kind of related question as I have the value numberOfTickets in the first method is there anyway to get the value into the public static double route() as i want to create a for loop where the number of tickets is the limiter on how high i can go ???

Comment: yes you pass that value in as a function parameter like this `public static double route(int numberOfTickets)` and then you use the variable `numberOfTickets` within the function. You must pass this value in when you call the function, otherwise the compiler will complain